# Loading data from api in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have code like this:

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      var ex_rate = data["market_price_usd"];
      document.getElementById('btcusd777').innerHTML = ex_rate;
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://blockchain.info/ru/stats?format=json');//&cors=true doesn't help
  xhr.send();
</script>
1 BTC = <span id="btcusd777"></span> USD
```

But it doesn't work because api is on different domain. Is there a way to fix it somehow? I don't want to use jquery

Comment: Read the first line [here in the docs](https://blockchain.info/en/api/blockchain_api). _"Some API calls are available with CORS headers if you add a cors=true parameter to the request"_. (CORS stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, and that's what you"re asking)

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/b7fbbdf5e6ad56443caae05dd60ce33a.png if I got you right, this doesn't help

Comment: There seems to be a dedicated URL for what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/5rwrh712/ But the value is fixed for 24 hours, not real time... :/ **Edit:** actually, it did just change, so maybe it's real time

Comment: thanks, this one is working, post it as answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://blockchain.info/en/api/blockchain_api) state that *"Some API calls are available with CORS headers if you add a cors=true parameter to the request."* But that does not seem to be the case for the call you made.

There seems to be another call that allows cross origin requests:

```
https://blockchain.info/ru/q/24hrprice
```

So just adjust your call like this:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById('btcusd777').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'https://blockchain.info/ru/q/24hrprice');
xhr.send();
```

```html
1 BTC = <span id="btcusd777"></span> USD
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to support CORS, so if you don't have control over the API development, that I guess it's the case, the only way to do it is by proxying it through your own web server.

If you have an nginx:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

If you are on apache:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Note that jquery or any other javascript framework will not help with this as it's a browser restriction. It doesn't seem to have crossdomain.xml file so flash will not help either.

Comment: obviously at first I was using my server for that, but it got banned by cloudflare after a few requests - that's why I decided to move it to clients

Comment: Then there's not too much to do to call that service... I'm glad blex found an alternative one for you :-). Good job man.